# Flutter Dio response type<!DOCTYPE html> not json

Tags: flutter, api, postman, dio

I'm using dio.post for the payment method
the API working well on Postman but when receiving the response is not a JSON type
It is   and then the app can not handle the response to a usable data

the main problem is that the payment don successfully but it gives an error to the user[this is the response.data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUuyW.png)

My Dio initialized as

```
  static init() {
  _dio = Dio(
    BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: baseUrl,
      receiveDataWhenStatusError: true,
      followRedirects: false,
      validateStatus: (status) {
      return status! < 500;
      },
    connectTimeout: 60 * 1000 ,
    // 60 seconds
    receiveTimeout: 60 * 1000 ,
    ),
  );
}
```

My Method is Post

```
static Future<Response> postData({
required String endPoint,
required dynamic data,
String? token,
 }) async {
// set headers here
_dio.options.headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
};
return await _dio.post(endPoint, data: data);
}
```

I send the request as this

```
String _fileName = counterImage.path.split('/').last;
        var _image = await MultipartFile.fromFile(
          counterImage.path,
          filename: _fileName,
          contentType: MediaType('image', 'png'),
        );
        FormData _data = FormData.fromMap({
          'my_wallet': mainWallet.id,
          'amount': amount,
          'product': product.id,
          'units_count': unitsCount,
          'image': _image,
        });

        await DioHelper.postData(
          endPoint: '$paymentEndPoint/$subWalletID',
          token: payToken,
          data: _data,
        ).then((value) {
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print('Pay done response ${value.data}');
          }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this in post Method (content-type):

```
static Future<Response> postData({
required String endPoint,
required dynamic data,
String? token,
 }) async {
// set headers here
_dio.options.headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
};
return await _dio.post(endPoint, data: data);
}
```